# Android onFling not responding

Tags: android

I am new to android first of all so think of any newbie mistakes first

I am trying to add a fling function in my code.

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnGestureListener {

private MainThread thread;
private Droid droid;
private Droid droid2;
private static final String TAG = gameView.class.getSimpleName();
private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

public MainGamePanel(Context context){
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        droid = new Droid(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.playerbox2), 270, 300);
        droid2 = new Droid(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.playerbox2), 50, 300);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
}


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    droid.draw(canvas);
    droid2.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float                         velocityY)
    {
         droid.setX(50);
        droid.setY(50);
        Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + e1.getX() + ",y=" + e2.getY());
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    droid2.setX((int)e.getX());
    droid2.setY((int)e.getY());


    Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + e.getX() + ",y=" + e.getY());
    return false;
}
```

I got the gestureListener to work with: onDown, onLongPress, and onShowPress.

But i can't get any response with onFling, onSingleTapUp, and onScroll.

What mistake am I making? does it have to do with views?

I don't know what code would be useful to see.... so any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Post the implementation of your listeners for more help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`onDown` is called before the `onFling` event.
If you return false in `onDown` method, the motion event propagation will stop.

Try to change `return false` in `return true` at the end of `onDown` method.

The return values are explained, somewhat obtusely, in the [Input Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners) page of the Dev guide. (scroll down below the example code to see).

Comment: Thank you exponentially for that very simple solution. I would have never guessed that

Comment: @Francesco Laurita : Your suggestion works.But onScroll() is called before onFling(). Fling is detected as onDown()..onScroll()..onScroll()....onFling(). But I have only overridden onDown() to return true. I have not overridden onScroll(). Still the code works, why?

Comment: This is an incredibly helpful answer, especially since the default implementation of onDown in SimpleOnGestureListener returns false. Thanks!

Comment: I found that this fixed the problem for me in most cases, such as when I wanted to detect onFling events on TextViews that previously didn't respond. But for reasons I don't understand it causes problems when trying to fling ListView's sideways - the position of the visible rows would often jump at the start of a drag event, but not always. So in the case of ListViews I just use the normal onDown event, since for me ListViews were responding to flings anyway.

Comment: What if we want to listen to both event onDown as well as onFling?

Answer (score 8):

You need to set your view longclickable, like this:

```
 yourView.setLongClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally we should not be.. GestureDetector works differently when associated with Activity Vs when  it is associated with View. There is already an issue reported.. [click here for more details](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8233).

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to change the setLongClickable to true.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    view.setLongClickable(true); // <---- here
    view.setOnTouchListener(getSwipeListener());

    return view;
}

public OnTouchListener getSwipeListener() {
    return new OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gesture = 
                new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
                        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, 
                            MotionEvent e2, 
                            float velocityX,
                            float velocityY) {
                        do some flinging here
                        return something
                    }
                });         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the return value of onDown method to true, it didn't work.
then i set
    ll_action_menu.setLongClickable(true);

it worked