# Why Fling gestures are not getting detected

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

I am trying to detect the `onFling` gestures by extending `SimpleOnGestureListener`. I also have checked some code on the web to know what I am missing but I did not notice any difference. The problem is with the `onFling`, `onDown` works. Please let me know what I am missing.

Code_Java:

```
private boolean setTouchableInfoDialog(LinearLayout infoReportContainer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "@setTouchableInfoDialog(): Inside setTouchableInfoDialog()");

        if (infoReportContainer == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "@setTouchableInfoDialog(): LinearLayout infoReportContainer Is NULL");
            return false;
        }else {
            final GestureDetector mGestiredetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new mSwipeGestureDetector());
            infoReportContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i(TAG, "@setTouchableInfoDialog()->onTouch(): Binding the LinearLayout infoReportContainer"
                            + " To the GestureDetector");
                    return mGestiredetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
        }
        return true;

    }

class mSwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 150;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Added Upon Update
                    Log.i(TAG, "@onFling(): Fling Gesture Detected");
        try {
            if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("@onFling(): ", "UpToDown Swipe");
                return true;
            }else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("@onFling(): ", "DownToUp Swipe");
                return true;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        //return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: add some logs in onFling

Comment: @pskink please scrol the code down, i think you did not see the onFling() body, there is some Logs. is that what you mean?

Comment: add logs that are always executed, not in some if statements

Comment: @pskink ok i updated the code, just added a Log statement. unfortunately it is not reachable?

Answer (score 0):

I think my mistake related to what I am returning from `onDown()`. `onDown()` is called before `onFling()` and if `onDown` returned false, then `onFling` will never be called.

I just changed the return value of `onDown` to be `true`. and `onFling` is working.

I refered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522637/android-onfling-not-responding)